# How to fix in cv.glmnet the Error of different rows?

Tags: r, computer-vision, cross-validation, glmnet

I try to Cross validate my data to get a good lambda parameter. The cross validation give me an error output because of different weights. I didn´t set up any wheigts so far.

i thought its a problem of the number of rows in `y.train` and `X.mat.train` but i looked at them and they have both an equal number `nrow = 80.000`.

```
set.seed(1234)
str(X.mat.train)
# num [1:80000, 1:36]    
str(y.train)
# num [1:80000] 

lambda.seq<- c(2^seq(3,-16,length=99),0)

cv.en <- cv.glmnet(X.mat.train, y.train, intercept=FALSE, standardize=TRUE,  alpha=0,5, nfold=10, lambda = lambda.seq)
```

My Output in the end is:

> Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda =
>   lambda,  :    number of elements in weights (1) not equal to the
>   number of rows of x (80000)

Any Idea?

Comment: can you give samples of your datasets in order to reproduce the error and try to understand it ?

Comment: I think it has to do with this: `alpha=0,5,`. Probably taking the 5 as weights

Comment: oh damn it was to late yesterday eving thanks @josemz that was the mistake.